# How to find the exact location details from latitude and longitude?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried using Google Maps API for 'Reverse Geocoding' to get the location by providing latitude and longitude. This gives the street address, city and country info. But I need to get the exact details like building name, shop name etc. For example, while querying the co-ordinates "72.9011206,19.0517508", Google Maps API gives "Plot No 5, VN Purav Marg, Borla, Union Park, Chembur, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India". But I need to get the name of the shop "Barista Lavazza" as available in 'Google Earth' for the same co-ordinate details.

Comment: NearBySearch of Places API (via places library) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: It looks like you might have your latitude and longitude reversed (lat: 72.9011206, lng:19.0517508) is in the sea north of Sweden, (lat:19.0517508, lng:72.9011206) is in Mumbai, India.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the [Google Maps Javscript API Places library nearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), search the returned results for the closest result to the requested position.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fx5L6tLp/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow;
var searchLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(19.0517508, 72.9011206);

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: searchLoc,
      zoom: 18,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var request = {
    location: searchLoc,
    radius: '50'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var distMin = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var idxMin = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      bounds.extend(results[i].geometry.location);
      var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(results[i].geometry.location, searchLoc);

      if (distance < distMin) {
        distMin = distance;
        idxMin = i;
      }
    }

    var marker = createMarker(results[idxMin]);
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent("<h2 style='color:blue'>"+place.name + "</h2><br>" + place.vicinity + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(7));
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The output of the code gives the right map. But my task requires the result in text format ("Barista Lavazza, Address.."). Any inputs on how to obtain such a result will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question qoesn't indicate that and is tagged [google-maps -api-3], what does "text format" mean? If the answer gets the data you need, you should be able to display it however you want.

Comment: My apologies for not making it clear. I was looking for a json response instead of a visual response on the map canvas. Would you know how to get a json response with the nearby place instead of street address?

Comment: Do the same thing as the javascript does in your code on the server (whatever language that might be, you didn't say) to the response from the webservice.

Comment: I tried another pair of co-ordinates in your code and I got the correct location. But when I run the below query with the same co-ordinates in the browser, I get multiple locations in the JSON result. It contains the location pointed by the map that your code gives as output. But it also has other locations too. How can I narrow down the result to just one location as in your output. I require the result in JSON format to use in my code. "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.1132208,72.8698591&radius=50&key=AIzaSyA9gwlXWvdGv3ykjnnRvJNED8k_6snxSj8"

Comment: My code chooses the closest result to the input coordinates, do that in your code as well.